# Xamarin Shared Library namespace cannot be found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, restsharp

My shared library cannot resolve `using RestSharp;` among other related namespaces. RestSharp is an installed package and is resolvable in the Droid/iOS projects but cannot be found in the Shared Library. I know this works because I'm using RestSharp in a MonoGame project in the same way. The shared library is referenced in the Droid/iOS projects but still fails during compilation.

Any advice? I tried clean all.

**Update** I created a new Cross Platform Native app solution and I was able to reference in my shared library without issue. That original project is a bit older and was created with PCL originally. I still want to know why it's not working in my original solution.

Comment: Have you added the RestSharp nuget package to your shared library?

Comment: @SushiHangover I don't believe you can add packages to shared libraries. Just PCL's or app projects.

Comment: Are you talking about a "Shared Project" or a "Shared Library"?, not the same thing...

Comment: @SushiHangover well now I'm uncertain. When adding to the existing solution I click MultiPlatform - **Library** - Shared **Project**. Whereas when creating a new solution for MultiPlatform native, you can choose to use PCL or Shared **Library**. The only difference I see between the two solutions is that the non-working one was originally created with PCL and the working with Shared Library.

Comment: It is really messed up  VS/VS4M use incorrect terminology (or just plain conflicting terms) in the different versions (IMO). A "Shared Project" is sharing source code files between each project that references them and some VS/VS4M versions are calling that a shared library (Maybe someone at MSFT is is thinking of a "Source Code Library", but library in the .Net world, to at least myself, is an self-contained assembly (.NetStd/PCL/...). The original one in your case is not a "Shared Project" as it is a PCL-based library, but the second one is (but they are now calling it a "Shared Library")

Answer (score 0):

I continued to have lots of namespace and type not found issues. Once I showed warnings instead of just errors I found that the csproj was missing. After removing the reference in the native apps and re-adding the issue was resolved. Quite frusterating.